# Add a key value after each JSON record

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have below JSON code, there is a need to add Key/Value to the end of each record as shown in sample. I'm using JOLT Transform processor for JSON transformation.

**Input**:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id",
    "emp_name": "emp_name",
    "emp_dept": "emp_dept",
    "email": "email"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "emp_name": "Jemimah",
    "emp_dept": "MacAiline",
    "email": "jmacailine0@huffingtonpost.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "emp_name": "Dorene",
    "emp_dept": "Elden",
    "email": "delden1@live.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "emp_name": "Gustave",
    "emp_dept": "Perott",
    "email": "gperott2@wufoo.com"
  }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id",
    "emp_name": "emp_name",
    "emp_dept": "emp_dept",
    "email": "email",
    "status": "status"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "emp_name": "Jemimah",
    "emp_dept": "MacAiline",
    "email": "jmacailine0@huffingtonpost.com",
    "status": "NEW"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "emp_name": "Dorene",
    "emp_dept": "Elden",
    "email": "delden1@live.com",
    "status": "NEW"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "emp_name": "Gustave",
    "emp_dept": "Perott",
    "email": "gperott2@wufoo.com",
    "status": "NEW"
  }
]
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would help you,

[Nifi - How to add key:value to json](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/106614/nifi-how-to-add-keyvalue-to-json-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@(0,id)": "[&].id",
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "id": {
          "id": {
            "#status": "[&3].status"
          },
          "*": {
            "#NEW": "[&3].status"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

if you needed to add only unique default key-value pair ***"status": "NEW"***, then managing getting the desired spec would be simpler through use of **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "status": "NEW"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the modify-overwrite-beta in your spec, as followed

```
 [
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "status": "NEW"
      }
    }
  }
]
```